# Add table of content to pdf's bookmarks, but suppress printing the actual page with the table of content

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf

Writing a short report in Latex with documentclass scrartcl. This kind of report does not have a table of content printed.

Viewing the PDF on a ereader I realised that it is rather useful to have a toc to navigate the document, although I don't want it to appear in the printed document. Is there a way do this?

All appendices B1 up to and including B6 are visible as bookmarks to de pdf created. After the title page there is no page with a table of content.

**Sample**
This is a shorter piece of code which hopefully shows better what I'm trying to achieve.

[image: bookmarks from appendices are shown]

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside,fontsize=12pt,
  parskip=full]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfsubject = {Recruitment},
    pdftitle = {artificial intelligence},
    pdfauthor = {Peter},
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
}


\begin{document}


\section*{introduction}

\blindtext

\section*{first section}

\blindtext

\section*{second section}

\blindtext


\newpage
\appendix
\section{B1. Formulier Onderzoeksthema en Vraagstelling}
\newpage
\section{B2. Peer Review Thema en Hoofdvraag}
\newpage
\section{B3. Peer Review Deelvragen}
\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.9]{b3.pdf}
\newpage
\section{B4. Peer Review Bronnenoverzicht}
\newpage
\section{B5. Peer Review Structuur}
\newpage
\section{B6. Peer Review Concept Rapportage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: yes, but you will have to provide a small complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Does adding the `hyperref` package help? That should be all that is needed in most circumstances. But if not, yes, we need a minimal working example to play with.

Comment: I added the code of main.tex and the preamble used.

Comment: (Without looking much at your code) You could try to use `\begingroup\setbox0\vbox{\tableofcontents}\endgroup`.

Comment: I can't test such a code. I don't have the files. Try to make a **small** example that **we** can use for a test. Remove irrelevant stuff like graphics that we don't have or the bibliography.

Comment: @Skillmon hyperref doesn't need such tricks to create bookmarks, the main question here is actually why they are missing.

Comment: I made a short piece of sample code and added a screenshot. In the screenshot you see that the appendices are added as bookmarks. I would like to do the same with the sections without adding a page with the table of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\section*` to create unnumbered sections. This also disables other useful things. Use `\addsec`:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,oneside,fontsize=12pt,
  parskip=full]{scrartcl}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    pdfsubject = {Recruitment},
    pdftitle = {artificial intelligence},
    pdfauthor = {Peter},
    hidelinks,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    urlcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue,
}


\begin{document}


\addsec{introduction}

\blindtext

\addsec{first section}

\blindtext

\addsec{second section}

\blindtext


\newpage
\appendix

\section{B1. Formulier Onderzoeksthema en Vraagstelling}
\newpage
\section{B2. Peer Review Thema en Hoofdvraag}
\newpage
\section{B3. Peer Review Deelvragen}
%\includepdf[pages=1,scale=0.9]{b3.pdf}
\newpage
\section{B4. Peer Review Bronnenoverzicht}
\newpage
\section{B5. Peer Review Structuur}
\newpage
\section{B6. Peer Review Concept Rapportage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is what I hoped to achieve!!